# High level of context switches when running Solr

Tags: solr

What is the best way to analyze why running Solr process(either inside Jetty or Tomcat) causes abnormally high rate of context switches? General parameters such as number of threads, memory etc. seems to be ok(verified via JMX), and Solr is under almost no load. Feeling a bit lost as to how fix the issue as I am not an expert on Solr :(

Comment: What is the reason for this analysis?  Are you trying to improve search performance/throughput?  How many processor cores do you have - compared to the number of concurrent searches?

Comment: Is it just a really high CPU usage or did you determine through some other means that it's context-switching? If it's consistently high CPU usage, I had to deal with that yesterday and I know exactly the solution. Let me know.

Comment: well, it was a leap second issue after all... oh well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a leap second related issue after all... Fixed by:

```
service ntp stop
date `date +"%m%d%H%M%C%y.%S"`
service ntp start
```